# Aborted (core dumped)

Tags: c, malloc

```
list->history=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));  
strcpy(list->history,pch2);
```

When I use the code above, I can't open the file more than once. It gives me this error:

> *** Error in `./exec2': malloc(): memory corruption: 0x00000000012060f0 ***
>   Aborted (core dumped)

How can I open the file more than once?

Comment: Not enough information. But your malloc is not correct. You are only allows acting a single byte

Answer (score 3):

Since `sizeof(char)` is 1, you are allocating 1 byte, and thus `strcpy` will have undefined behaviour unless the source string is empty.

Don't use `strcpy`; use [`strncpy`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html) instead, and be mindful of your allocation size and of the null termination:

```
size_t N = 1;   // or anything you deem suitable

list->history = malloc(N);
strncpy(list->history, pch2, N - 1);  // safe
list->history[N - 1] = '\0';
```

(Actually, the situation is a bit dire, since neither `strcpy` nor `strncpy` are absolutely good functions. By itself, `strcpy` isn't safe since you can't control the output buffer size, and `strncpy` is inefficient since it writes more zeros than what may be desired; neither return a pointer to the last copied character. Moreover, the collection `strncpy`, `strncat` and `snprintf` is horribly inconsistent about the meaning of the length parameter and whether and how null terminators are added.)

Comment: ... and lacking the null character (sometimes)

Comment: @clement_frndz: `memcpy` doesn't work since it doesn't scan for the source terminator and will thus cause UB when the source string is shorter than `N`.

Comment: You're right on this one, but I wrote this comment assuming he malloc'ed the exact length of his string + 1.

Comment: @clement_frndz: And I wasn't making any assumptions :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB Yeah but in the case where pch2 is longer than N - 1 the buffer won't be NULL terminated anyways :-p. Adding `list->history[N - 1] = '\0'` is a free security here since it "should" already be there in most cases. (Which my memcpy solution doesn't offer though)

Comment: @KerrekSB not in the case where pch2 is longer than N-1.

Answer (score 1):

Your `malloc()` is faulty, it does not allocated enough memory to the pointer to be used as a destination string in `strpy()`.

My suggestion : get rid of both `malloc()` and `strcpy()`/`strncpy()`, use `strdup()`. Better.

Simply, use

```
list->history = strdup(pch2);
```

See [here](http://blog.liw.fi/posts/strncpy/), why **not** to use `strncpy()`.

Comment: There's no `strdup` in C :-(

Comment: @KerrekSB Agree, but isn't it POSIX, which is accepted in general?

Answer (score -1):

I solved it, here's the improved code:

```
a=strlen(pch2);

list->history=(char*)malloc(a*sizeof(char) + 1);

strcpy(list->history, pch2);
```

Comment: Nope. There's no room for the terminating \0. You need to malloc(a*sizeof(char) + 1). strlen("abc") = 3, but str[3] = '\0' which makes 4 characters. Your solution may work as well as it may cause a Bus Error.

Comment: I like the approach though. Break down a one liner that is not working into multiple lines helps to identify the core of the problem. If you cannot break the problem down into smaller and smaller sections to find the problem, then you likely don't own the code.